# In the US, can a job with a religious institution require that I am a member of that institution?

Tags: job-search, recruitment, legal

I have seen job postings like the following:

- Software Development Engineer 5
- Company Name = The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints
- Company Location = Riverton

https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/879341343/

Stating things like:

> Worthiness Qualification
>
> Must be a member of The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints and currently temple worthy.

Is this legal?

Answer (score 19):

That job listing is in Utah, in the United States, so I will answer for the US.

Yes, it is legal. As the Equal Employment Opportunity Commission says, "Religious corporations, associations, educational institutions, or societies are exempt from the federal laws that EEOC enforces when it comes to the employment of individuals based on their particular religion."

The employer in that job listing is a religious organization.

See https://www.eeoc.gov/laws/practices/inquiries_religious.cfm

Comment: Normally this exception is for ministers of the church and so on not run of the mill employees  and the page you quote says "may lean"  and a doubt that  software development is a "bona fide occupational qualification"

Comment: Some additional context: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministerial_exception .

If you contribute to spreading the org's message, you count as a "minister". Even if it's not your primary role.

Comment: Organizations like this have religious duties and leadership-like expectations for their staff.  It is NOT going to be a "code monkey" job at all.  If you're senior enough, you will most likely have meetings with religious leaders.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this legal?

Since the employer is listed as "The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints Company Location Riverton", then Yes - this is legal.

Answer (score -4):

You haven't said which location (although there is good reason to assume it is somewhere in the USA, and I might even guess the state). If it is a position where your religion is essential, like a religious teacher or a priest, it would be legal. For an accountant, probably not. But this is all missing the point, because legal questions are off-topic here.

On the other hand, what are you going to do? Personally, I wouldn't want that job at all, no matter what the job is. If they don't agree with my religion or lack thereof, they can keep their job. (That's the polite version). You can probably go to court about it, you might even win, but it would be a waste of your time and money. So best for you to just ignore it.